# Unbearably slow redis connection when using openvpn

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openvpn, node.js, redis

I have an OpenVPN config file like the following:

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote SOME_REMOTE_SERVER 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_mccDtH70s3fYYV1g name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
# ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
# setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

When starting a Node server with OpenVPN on, it connects to the Redis server without any problem. However, when I actually use that connection to get / set data, it timed out. Calling MongoDB queries from the server work with a bit of delay. SSH-ing to the end server also timed out.

Getting, setting keys from Redis GUI still works seamlessly, this config also works without any problem on macOS and Windows, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Does anyone know how to fix this and why this happens to Ubuntu? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with DNS resolution for hostnames that reside in your routed network. This often happens when someone new to OpenVPN sets it up.
Did you try connecting to services using an IP address or just hostnames?

Comment: There was not any hostname, an IP address is there since the beginning.